# inconsistency of redirecting sys.stderr in IPython and console

Tags: python, console, ipython, stderr, redirect

Redirecting sys.stderr to a text file in IPython and console(Gnome terminal) yields different results.

```
f=open('std.log','w')
sys.stderr=f
raise Exception,"message goes here"
```

In IPython, the error message is printed directed into the screen.

```
In [13]: run std.py

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/xiaohan/code/diving-in-python/htmlparser/std.py in <module>()
      2 f=open('std.log','w')
      3 sys.stderr=f
----> 4 raise Exception,"message goes here"
      5 
      6

Exception: message goes here
WARNING: Failure executing file: <std.py>
```

However, if I ran it in console directly.

```
python std.py
```

The error message is hidden and redirected to the text file.

Any suggestions on what is going on here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is **not** writing to `stderr`, but IPython's `run` command intercepting exceptions.  When the program raises an unhandled exception, IPython will print the backtrace to its own console, plus an additional warning (*WARNING: Failure executing file*).  This is done by installing an exception hook function as `sys.excepthook`.

If you explicitely write to `sys.stderr` in your test script, it will get written to the log file as expected.

To see the exception hook, add `print(sys.excepthook)` to your script.  When executed directly, it will be `<built-in function excepthook>`, within IPython, something like `<bound method InteractiveShell.excepthook of <IPython.iplib.InteractiveShell object at 0x022FA3F0>>`.